# Are NFL teams disallowed from practising with NCAA teams?

Tags: american-football, nfl, collegiate

Ignoring whether this would actually happen, is there any rule that would prohibit a NFL team or unit (OL, DL, etc.) from practising with a NCAA football team or unit?

Would the NCAA consider it tampering in some form?

Comment: Might depend on how you define "practice with".  The Chicago Bears regularly practice during preseason at the U of I facilities, but I don't think they directly take part in large college practices or anything like that (probably for obvious reasons).

Comment: @Joe True, many NFL teams will practice at NCAA facilities and there are stories here-and-there about QBs throwing to college WRs in the early off-season (or during suspensions...), but I haven't heard of more "official" setups. It makes sense why they don't (they have practice squads for a reason), but is there actually any legal prohibition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Not even getting into the weird NCAA rules - which I am sure this would violate many - it violates the current collective bargaining agreement in the NFL.

First NFL teams can only practice with other NFL teams in designated scrimmages before the start of the regular season.  And simply any player practicing with a team (or a team of players) without an NFL contract would be in direct violation of the NFL player's union contract.  Coach's can't even give a former NFL player a try-out during a practice.  No contract = no practice.